# Vue3 Vite Hot Reload (HMR) no working in the browser

Tags: vuejs3, vite, hot-reload

I'm developing a vue3 project with vite.
The HMR doesn't working fine in my dev enviroment.
When a vue file edited, vite handle the change and send a message thru websocket correctly

```
{"type":"update",
"updates":[{"type":"js-update","timestamp":1669740364450,"path":"/src/views/user/LoginView.vue","explicitImportRequired":false,"acceptedPath":"/src/views/user/LoginView.vue"}]}
```

but in the browser (I tried different ones) nothing happened.
Any solution?

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontendq",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.9.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.15.5",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "quasar": "^2.10.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.45",
    "vue-i18n": "9",
    "vue-recaptcha": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vue3-cookies": "^1.0.6",
    "vuex": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
    "sass": "1.32.12",
    "vite": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.2.4"
}
```

Comment: Make new project with same package.json and vite.config.js and src works.

Clearing node_modules, yarn cache --all not solve the problem.

I don't understand..

Answer (score 14):

I've been dealing with this issue in a project with Vue 3, TypeScript and Vite 4. I added the next to my `vite.config.ts` to fix the hot reload:

```
server: {
  watch: {
    usePolling: true,
  }
},
```

My entire `vite.config.ts`:

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    }
  },
});
```

Added:

The `usePolling` setting makes Vite regularly check files for changes. It's helpful in certain environments, like containers, network file systems, or Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 in some cases, where normal file change detection doesn't work well. However, using `usePolling` can make your CPU work harder, as Vite's documentation warns: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-watch

Comment: Please add an explanation of provided configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I've spent hours trying to find the solution, and that's the only one that worked.

Answer (score 4):

Just my two cents; I've been having this problem lately, and the solution was as simple as switching all of my files and folders to camel case.

When I clone the project to a separate computer, HMR stops working; the page simply reloads without being updated. HMR works properly on all files in my main dev machine.

Then I realized that there were a few file and folder names that were different between my local files and those in my repository. On my main machine, a few files that start with capital letters are lowercase in git. So, I changed the case of all of my files and folders to camel, and now everything is working.

Comment: My problem was I renamed a vue file changing its case.  HMR stopped working on that file.   I renamed it again to a completely different name and HMR started up again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, need to check correctly importing vue templates, if name in **CamelCase** need import in the same **CamelCase**, or **kebab-kase**, it also can affect on hmr.

```
<script setup>
import Quiz from "./components/Quizeeeez.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <main class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-full text-2xl">
    <Quiz class="max-w-2xl" />
  </main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here and the other solutions are not working, double check your `vite` config and make sure the plugin order is proper. I was calling `Windi` after `Vue` and fixing this order fixed my HMR issue.

Current config that let Hot Reload start working again:

```
export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    WindiCSS(),
    vue() // Originally called first
  ]
})
```